# Another way to calculate the average point of each student in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database

I have three below tables. I want to write a statement that show student ID, student names and the average point of each student. Please look at the tables:

---

Grade_table

```
student_ID  courses_names     how many_times         grade
91110010003     MCB                 1                  7
91110010003     THDC                1                  8
91110010003     THVP                1                 9.5
91110010004     MCB                 1                 4.5
91110010004     THDC                1                 5.5
91110010004     THVP                1                 10
```

---

Courses tables

```
Courses_ID    courses names      period of time
  CSDL          database                30
  MCB          Basic network            30
  THDC        Basic computers           45
  THVP       Concepts of office         45
  XLA           Photoshop               45
```

---

Student table

```
studentID         fullname        gender         DOB            classID
91110010003          A             M          03/03/1993       25CCHT02
91110010004          B             M          08/03/1993       25CCHT02
91110010005          C             M          04/14/1991       25CCHT02
93510010005          D             M          07/27/1993       25CCDH02
93510010008          E             F          03/10/1993       25CCDH02
93510010009          F             M          06/09/1990       25CCDH02
93510010010          G             M          18/12/1989       25CCDH02
99510170307          H             M          05/06/1991       25CCDH02
99510180112          L             M          07/12/1992       25CCDH02
99510180150          M             M          22/03/1993       25CCDH02
```

Comment: 1. There is no column `student name` in the tables that you provided. 2. What do you mean by `average point of each student`? Average grade perhaps?

Comment: average point of each student ??

Comment: sorry about that, I have just added my student table

Comment: If `how many_times` is larger than `1`, will there be another record for each of their other attempts?  If so, will we be using only the most recent for the average or all of them?

Comment: Please format your tables.

Comment: the 'how many_times' means that the number of times a student takes an exam. I don't think you would need it

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following...

```
SELECT Student_table.studentID,
       Student_table.fullname,
       COALESCE( CAST( AVG( grade ) AS DECIMAL( 11, 2 ) ), 'N/A' ) AS average_grade
FROM Student_table
LEFT JOIN Grade_table ON Student_table.studentID = Grade_table.student_ID
GROUP BY Student_table.studentID;
```

This statement starts by performing a `LEFT JOIN` on `Student_table` and `Grade_table` on their shared values of `student_ID`.  `Courses_table` is not needed for this exercise.

It then groups the resulting dataset by each student and calculates the mean average for each student using the `AVG()` function.  If the student has no `Grade_table` entries, then `AVG()` will return a `NULL` value.  `COALESCE()` will return the mean average if `AVG()` returned a non-`NULL` value and `N/A` if a `NULL` value was returned.

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.

*Addendum*

I have tested my statement against a dataset created using the following script...

```
CREATE TABLE Grade_table
(
    student_ID       LONG,
    courses_names    VARCHAR( 5 ),
    how_many_times   INT,
    grade            DOUBLE
);
INSERT INTO Grade_table ( student_ID,
                          courses_names,
                          how_many_times,
                          grade )
VALUES ( 91110010003, 'MCB',  1, 7 ),
       ( 91110010003, 'THDC', 1, 8 ),
       ( 91110010003, 'THVP', 1, 9.5 ),
       ( 91110010004, 'MCB',  1, 4.5 ),
       ( 91110010004, 'THDC', 1, 5.5 ),
       ( 91110010004, 'THVP', 1, 10 );
CREATE TABLE Student_table
(
    studentID    LONG,
    fullname     VARCHAR( 50 ),
    gender       CHAR( 1 ),
    DOB          DATE,
    classID      CHAR( 8 )
);
INSERT INTO Student_table ( studentID,
                            fullname,
                            gender,
                            DOB,
                            classID )
VALUES ( 91110010003, 'A', 'M', '1993-03-03', '25CCHT02' ),
       ( 91110010004, 'B', 'M', '1993-03-08', '25CCHT02' ),
       ( 91110010005, 'C', 'M', '1991-04-14', '25CCHT02' ),
       ( 93510010005, 'D', 'M', '1993-07-27', '25CCDH02' ),
       ( 93510010008, 'E', 'F', '1993-10-03', '25CCDH02' ),
       ( 93510010009, 'F', 'M', '1990-09-06', '25CCDH02' ),
       ( 93510010010, 'G', 'M', '1989-12-18', '25CCDH02' ),
       ( 99510170307, 'H', 'M', '1991-06-05', '25CCDH02' ),
       ( 99510180112, 'L', 'M', '1992-12-07', '25CCDH02' ),
       ( 99510180150, 'M', 'M', '1993-03-22', '25CCDH02' );
```

Comment: Added explanation to question.

Comment: You're welcome.  If an Answer solves your problem, and if it is the most suitable Answer of those available, then you can accept it by clicking on the tick next to the top of the Answer.  This gives the answerer a 15 point reward and removes the Question from StackOverflow's list of unanswered Questions.

Comment: There are only two students appears on the grade table.  I also want to show the rest students with a 'null' or 'N/A' score . How can I do that ?

Comment: It works without errors but the result only shows the two students appearing on the grade table and the average grade show 'BLOB'.  I don't know what this mean. Do you have another idea ?

Comment: I have corrected my code to (hopefully) deal with the `BLOB` problem.  As for the other, I shall work up a test database and figure it out.  Note, you can improve a Question's quality by not only showing the table(s) structure with sample data, but also including a script to create those tables and populate them with your data.

Comment: Jeez, what does a guy have to do to get a vote around here? You're too nice, toonice!

Comment: Strawberry, My longest attempt at an Answer took about 5 days, a couple of dozen Comments and two chat sessions.  I actually quite enjoyed it - it was very stimulating.  This is very mild in comparison.